# How Do I Encrypt AES256 CTR with a Plain Text Password?

Tags: go, encryption, aes

I'm working with this [example](https://golang.org/pkg/crypto/cipher/#example_NewCTR) to try to encrypt data using AES-256. However, when I use the password `WeakPasswordForTesting` as input, I get an error: `crypto/aes: invalid key size`. I get the impression that it has to do with my plain password length. How can I use this example code to encrypt the data using a short plain-text password?

```
func Encrypt(password []byte, plainSource []byte) ([]byte, error) {
    key, _ := hex.DecodeString(string(password))
    block, err := aes.NewCipher(key)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    // The IV needs to be unique, but not secure. Therefore it's common to
    // include it at the beginning of the ciphertext.
    ciphertext := make([]byte, aes.BlockSize+len(plainSource))
    iv := ciphertext[:aes.BlockSize]
    if _, err := io.ReadFull(rand.Reader, iv); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    stream := cipher.NewCTR(block, iv)
    stream.XORKeyStream(ciphertext[aes.BlockSize:], plainSource)

    return ciphertext, nil
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The [Advanced Encryption Standard (AES)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Encryption_Standard) is a [block cipher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher) which expects a key of a fixed size. The key length is in the name of the cipher: AES-**256** means a key length of 256 bits.

As your password is not a key which conforms to this spec, you need to implement a process to make it so. A common mechanism is a *key derivation function*, which takes an input passphrase of entropy significantly lower than the desired key length, and pads it with various data to produce a key of the required length. The [PBKDF family](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PBKDF2) (password-based key derivation function) is an example of this, as is [scrypt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scrypt).

---

You should not implement a naïve mechanism to pad your input data in this way, as the security of a good cryptosystem is entirely dependent on the quality of the key, and it is highly unlikely any homegrown solution will be  resistant to a variety of attacks.

[This question](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/46955/7039) on crypto.SE may be interesting regarding a more thorough assessment of implementation recommendations using PBKDF2.

Comment: Excellent answer, covers all the nuances.